# Material UI Layout divide by angle line

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to implement ui like image below.taken from [here](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/408631366167394581/) . Layout divide by angle line in half.Don't have any idea how to implement it.Any help will be appreciated. Not getting any hint from web

[image]

Comment: Not an expert, but I believe it might be just a static image.

Comment: @MKII No I just wanted how to divide screen in angle idea.already done in Yahoo News Digest app.take look.

Comment: I was actually looking into that and I was wondering how is it implemented in the yahoo news digest, I guess it is as @MKII said they add a triangular image on the top left side of your list and clip it to the view

Comment: Maybe. Dont know exactly how to implement it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after long search i found this sample [Android-Diagonal-Cut-View](https://github.com/hidrodixtion/Android-Diagonal-Cut-View)

Height of item need to be declare in XML. Add XML in drawable use below code snippet.

**Drawable - background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<item>
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/bebe" android:gravity="center" android:alpha="0.1"/>
</item>

<item android:top="300dp"
    android:bottom="-300dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-300dp">
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="-10"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="100%">
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
</shape>
</rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**Usage :**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />
```